# Blocks example in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, block

I am a bit familier with the concepts of Blocks but I don't know how to create them in iOS5. Can anyone provide me  with a simple example ? Much appreciated :)

Comment: you can understand about block concepts then why you can.t use in objective c

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176961/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-blocks) question asked by SKM.

Comment: Here is a link which you are looking for 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176961/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this simple example in Blocks..

```
int multiplier = 7;
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
return num * multiplier;
};



NSLog(@"Sum = %d",myBlock(20));
Then you will get as 140
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example. Hope it helps.

```
void (^name)(void) = ^ {
//insert code here
};
```